# Changing text and class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been stuck all day on a project I'm working on. All funcitonality is there, I'm just having trouble with the jquery, can someone help me out?

here is a visual of the application:

[image: http://imgur.com/nsdgubB]

Pretty simple, when I click "like post" a function is called via ajax to run a update to the count on the database, also the same when I press "Dislike"

My problem is with the JQuery, I can't seem to figure out how to make it so when "Like post" is clicked, it is changed to "Already Liked" and the "Already Disliked" changed to "Dislike"

CSS Classes:

```
    "Like Post" = fa fa-thumbs-up like_btn
    "Dislike Post" = fa fa-thumbs-down dislike_btn
    "Already Liked" = fa fa-check like_btn
    "Already Disliked" = fa fa-check fa-check-dislike dislike_btn"
```

Here is the current JQuery, I've tried a few different things but nothing seems to be working, any suggestions I greatly appreciate.

```
$('.fa-thumbs-up').click(function() {

var annid = $(this).attr('id');
update_likes(annid, 'like');
//code goes here
});

$('.fa-thumbs-down').click(function() {

var annid = $(this).attr('id');
update_likes(annid, 'dislike');
//code goes here
});
```

UPDATED JFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/T9wvL/2/

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle with what you currently have, without knowing the markup (html) it is hard to assist.

Comment: Can you explain what did you try? Because that can point where the problem might be.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of specificity, I put together a little fiddle to hopefully explain my issue a little more, thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T9wvL/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<article>
    <div class="updates-like">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up like_btn" id="<? echo $update->annid; ?>">
            <span>Like Post </span>
        </i> 
    </div>
    <div class="updates-dislike">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike_btn" id="<?echo $update->annid;?>">
            <span>No Good</span>
        </i> 
    </div>
</article>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.like_btn').click(function () {
    /*This here runs the update function on the DB.. Not Important
       var annid = $(this).attr('id');
       update_likes(annid, 'like');*/

        //Code here to change "Like Post" to "already Liked" ON CLICK, and to change "already disliked" back to "No Good"

    if ( $(this).hasClass('fa-thumbs-up') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-thumbs-up')
               .addClass('fa-check')
               .find('span')
               .text('Already Liked');
        if ( $('.dislike_btn').hasClass('fa-check fa-check-dislike') ) {
            $('.dislike_btn').removeClass('fa-check fa-check-dislike')
                             .addClass('fa-thumbs-down')
                             .find('span')
                             .text('No Good');
        }
    }

    return true;

});

$('.dislike_btn').click(function () {
    /*This here runs the update function on the DB.. Not Important
        var annid = $(this).attr('id');
        update_likes(annid, 'dislike'); */

        //Code here to change "No Good" to "already disliked" ON CLICK, and to change "already Liked" back to "No Like Post"

    if ( $(this).hasClass('fa-thumbs-down') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-thumbs-down')
               .addClass('fa-check fa-check-dislike')
               .find('span')
               .text('Already Disliked');
        if ( $('.like_btn').hasClass('fa-check') ) {
            $('.like_btn').removeClass('fa-check')
                          .addClass('fa-thumbs-up')
                          .find('span')
                          .text('Like Post');
        }
    }

    return true;

});
```

Here is the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9wvL/11/)** that should work for what you need. I tried to optimize a little bit your code, but I hope it still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to toggle elements than to swap text, so I modified your HTML a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/T9wvL/8

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

<article>
    <div class="updates updates-like">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up like_btn" id="like"> 
            <span>Like Post</span>
            <span class="hide">Already liked</span>
        </i> 
    </div>

    <div class="updates updates-dislike">
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike_btn" id="dislike">
            <span>No Good</span>
            <span class="hide">Already disliked</span>
        </i>
    </div>
</article>

$('.updates').click(function () {
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-thumbs-up fa-thumbs-down')
        .find('span').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: Updated again with logic fix.

Comment: thanks isherwood for the alternative method. I'm on my way home and will tweak a little more,I really do appreciate it. the only thing is when the like is toggled to "already liked" the other one needs to be set off. so when already liked is on, "no good" needs to be turned on and vice versa.