# JQuery Toggle / Class Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a particular issue that I've been stuck on for about a day, and would really appreciate any sort of direction.

Here is my current JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9wvL/2/

The functionality I need is pretty straight forward:
Pretty much, there are two options for each side. On the left: "Like Post" or "Already Liked."
On the right: "No Good" or "Already Disliked."

I need it so when "like Post" is clicked, I need it to be toggled to "Already Liked." When Already Liked is toggled on, I also need "No Good" to be the right option, and when "No Good" is clicked, I need it to be toggled to "Already Disliked," at the same time toggling "Already Liked" back to "Like Post" on the left side and vise versa.

In the current Jfiddle I have my current set up, I'm open to any suggestions. The Html needs to pretty much remain the same as far as the id's go, since they are important to a few various functions.

here are the classes:

```
"Like Post" = fa fa-thumbs-up like_btn
"Dislike Post" = fa fa-thumbs-down dislike_btn
"Already Liked" = fa fa-check like_btn
"Already Disliked" = fa fa-check fa-check-dislike dislike_btn"
```

Also, here's a visual of the app:

[image: App Image]

Comment: How's this different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378140/changing-text-and-class-with-jquery)?

Comment: It wasn't answered ;) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @tcornell05 You should edit the previous question (or offer a bounty) rather than open a new one. Please review the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to review the SO guidelines.

Comment: and remove this one. . . lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the following to your JavaScript:

```
$('.updates-like').click(function () {
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-thumbs-up").addClass("fa-check").parent().find("span").text("Already liked");
    $(".updates-dislike i").removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-thumbs-down").parent().find("span").text("No Good");
});

$('.updates-dislike').click(function () {
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-thumbs-down").addClass("fa-check").parent().find("span").text("Already disliked");
    $(".updates-like i").removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-thumbs-up").parent().find("span").text("Like Post");
});
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9wvL/10/)